# I have Account table and that have many relation with post and post have many relation with dailylog table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

i want to get all accounts with sum of likes column from log table just lastest log
i tried lot of way but no one is working

```php
TikTokAccount::whereHas('accountStat')
    ->with(['accountStat'])
    ->withCount(['postedVideos' => function ($query) {
        $query->withSum('lastestPostLog', function ($query) {
            $query->select('views_24h');
        });
    }])
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed it like this but I am showing data in server-side table so the order and filter column is not working

```
$data = \App\Models\TikTokAccount::whereHas('accountStat')->whereHas('postedVideos')->with('accountStat','postedVideos.latest_video_daily_info')->get();
    $data[0]->postedVideos->sum('latest_video_daily_info.comments_24h');
```